# Plot with different line style when clicked

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, dynamic, gui-construction, eventhandler

I have a plots with many lines and would like to be able to highlight lines when clicked (or on mouseover). When the data plotted is small this works well

```
styles = {Automatic, Automatic};
Dynamic@ListStepPlot[
  MapIndexed[
    EventHandler[#,
      {"MouseClicked" :> 
        (styles[[#2[[1]]]] = 
           styles[[#2[[1]]]] /. {Thick -> Automatic, Automatic -> Thick})}] &,
    {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 5}}],
  PlotStyle -> styles]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But my data is large and including the complete `ListStepPlot` inside `Dynamic` makes it very slow.

So I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
styles = {Automatic, Automatic};
ListStepPlot[
  MapIndexed[
    EventHandler[#,
      {"MouseClicked" :> 
        (styles[[#2[[1]]]] = 
           styles[[#2[[1]]]] /. {Thick -> Automatic, Automatic -> Thick})}] &,
    {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 5}}],
  PlotStyle -> Dynamic[styles]]
```

I know that `Dynamic` can be used for some `Plot` options values but apparently not for `PlotStyle`. Is there a way to make this work efficiently for large data sets?

Comment: How fast/slow is this for your data: `ListStepPlot[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 5}}, 
  BaseStyle -> Thick] /. {styles__, l_Line} :> {styles, 
   MouseAppearance[Dynamic@Mouseover[{Thin, l}, {Thick, l}], 
    "LinkHand"]}`?

Comment: This works very well! I had never seen Dynamic being injected like that inside a graphics object.

Comment: Oh @Kuba I see you got to the answer before I did

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: more efficient and more flexible solution:

```
ListStepPlot[
    {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 5}}, BaseStyle -> Thick
] /. {styles__, l_Line} :> DynamicModule[
    {edge = Thin}
  , {styles
    , Dynamic @ edge
    , MouseAppearance[
          EventHandler[
              l
            , "MouseClicked" :> (edge = edge /. {Thick -> Thin, Thin -> Thick} )
          ]
        , "LinkHand"
      ]
    }
 ]
```

---

Here is the old fix. Not the best as it doubles the size of the `GraphicsBox`:

```
ListStepPlot[
    {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 5}}, BaseStyle -> Thick
] /. {styles__, l_Line} :> {
    styles
  , MouseAppearance[Dynamic@Mouseover[{Thin, l}, {Thick, l}], "LinkHand"]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it by post-processing the `Plot`:

```
styleFloops =
  Map[RandomColor[] &, Range[2]];
styles =
  Map[Directive[ColorData[97][#], Thickness@Medium] &, Range[2]];
ListStepPlot[
  MapIndexed[
   EventHandler[#, {"MouseClicked" :> (styles[[#2[[1]]]] = 
         styles[[#2[[1]]]] /. {Thick -> Thickness@Medium, 
           Thickness@Medium -> Thick})}] &, {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 5}}],
  PlotStyle ->
   styleFloops
  ] /.
 MapIndexed[
  Directive[a___, #, b___] :>
    Dynamic[Directive[a, styles[[First@#2]], b]] &,
  styleFloops
  ]
```

It works under the assumption that `RandomColor` will never be the `Axes` color and will never intersect. I think that's reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`FlipView`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FlipView.html) to flip through a list of styles on each mouse click:

```
styles = {Thin, AbsoluteThickness[3], Directive[Thick, Dashed]};

ListStepPlot[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 5}}] /. 
  l_Line :> MouseAppearance[FlipView @ Thread[{ styles, l}], "SampleStyle"] // Deploy
```

[image]